# Access database remotely to fetch data

Tags: php, html, reactjs, database, remote-access

I need to access a database remotely using PHP and display the fetched data in html. My code is as below

```
$servername = "192.168.56.1:3306";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "grh";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  error_log("Failed to connect to database!", 0);
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); 
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM ip_patient_logs";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$rows = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $rows[] = $r;
    }
    print json_encode($rows);
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

I expected to be able to connect to the database and fetch the data , but it displays blank page. I am a beginner in PHP.

Comment: Have you check the error log? Or [display error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display). Oh, and PHP pages start with `<?php`, but I guess you left that out on purpose?

Comment: have you tried using echo json_encode($rows) instead or print?

Comment: Enable error reporting: add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli` errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: @Nicolas Tome
yes tried with echo, but same issue

Comment: @ KIKO Software yes

Comment: You are using `print json_encode` in part of your code and `echo` in other parts, Are you using JS fetch or any other async technique? If the final query result is used in JS you should use `echo json_encode("x results")`